# AngularJS form attributes in directive controller

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive credit-card

view : `credit-card.html`

```
<form name="form" novalidate="" id="creditCardAmountInputForm" ng-submit="submit()">
  <div class="form-group col-md-5" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form.amount.$invalid }">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder='{{ "dashboard.buyer.home.wallet_to_wallet.placeholders.amount" | translate }}'
    ng-model="transaction.amount" cent-number="" name="amount" required="" server-error="" max="2500">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button ng-disabled="user.status != 'activated'" type="submit" ladda="loading" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{ "dashboard.buyer.home.wallet_to_wallet.submit" | translate }}</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

controller : `credit-card.coffee``

```
angular.module 'App'
  .directive 'creditCard', ->
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/partials/credit-card.html'
    controller: ($rootScope, $scope, ENV, $window, transaction, notifications) ->
      $scope.user = $rootScope.user
      $scope.wallet = $scope.user.user_wallets[0]
      $scope.transaction = {}

      $scope.submit = ->
        new transaction(
          receiver_id: $scope.user.wallet_uuid
          amount: $scope.transaction.amount
          currency: "EUR"
       )
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the attribute `$scope.transaction.amount` is undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Mike

Comment: When do you get this error? Only when no value has been entered into the number input?

Comment: it's not an error, when I enter a number in the input, $scope.transaction.amount is undefined

Comment: You haven't created a `$scope.transaction` object, so you can't try to set its properties.  Add `$scope.transaction = {}` after `$scope.data = {}`

Comment: It was a typo, I renamed the variable for the post. Still no luck

Comment: actually it was a really stupid mistake. the max value was in cents. I debugged it by showing the value in the view. Thanks all for your help